# Angular 13 - Download file from ByteArray data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file, download

I get a `byte[]` file from my server with the content of a file. I know the name and the `content-type`. So far I have tried the following for downloading the file:

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style.display = 'none';

const file = new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'});
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.href = url;
a.download = "test.txt";
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

But this solution just downloads a text file with the binary content in it. How can I convert the binary data to the correspondent file type in the client side using JavaScript/Typescript? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

`import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`

```
const file = new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'});
FileSaver.saveAs(file, "test.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
saveByteArray(bytes, type) {
  var blob = new Blob([bytes],{type:type});
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = "fileName";
  link.click();
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 c#.net:
 public byte[] DocContent { get; set; }

Angular: 
DocContent:ArrayBuffer;

typescript: 
var content= this.base64ToArrayBuffer(response.DocContent);
        var blob = new Blob([content], { type: response.ContentType });

base64ToArrayBuffer(base64: any): ArrayBuffer {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
  }
```